# Waiting for state to change in react with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, react-redux

i am using redux in react-native to fetch data from an api, here is whhat i have done so far

api_type.js

```
export const USER_LOGIN = 'user_login_action';
export const USER_LOGINING = 'logining_users';
export const USER_LOGEDIN = 'user_logged_in';
```

index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { USER_LOGIN, USER_WALLETS,USER_LOGINING } from './api_types';

const AUTH_API_URL = 'http:/api/v1';
const CORE_API_URL = 'http:/api/v1';
let username="";
let password="";
let auth_token ="";
let AuthStr = "";

export function UserWallets(){

return function(dispatch){
    AuthStr ="Bearer "+auth_token;
    console.log ("new auth : "+AuthStr);
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AuthStr
    axios.get(`${CORE_API_URL}/wallet/allwallets`)
    .then(response => {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_WALLETS,
            payload: response['data'] 
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
export function UserLogin() {
 return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({
        type:USER_LOGINING
    });

    axios.post(
         `${AUTH_API_URL}/authenticate/users`,
          {
            email: username,
            password: password
          }

    ) 
   .then(response => {
      dispatch({
       type: USER_LOGIN,
       payload: response['data'] 
      });
      auth_token=response['data']['token'];

    } 

  )
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
   })
 }
}

export function username(term) {
  username=term; 
  console.log("username " +username);
  return{
   type:"username",
   username
  };
}
export function password(term) {
  password=term; 
  console.log("password " +password);
  return{
   type:"password",
   password
 };
}
export function authToken (term){
  auth_token = term;
  return{
    type:"authtoken",
    auth_token
  }
}
```

auth_reducer.js

```
import { USER_LOGIN ,USER_LOGINING } from '../actions/api_types';

  const INTIAL_STATE = { 
    message: '',
    token:'',
    logging: false,
    loggedin: false,
    loginerr: null,
  };

export default function (state = INTIAL_STATE, action) {
  console.log("present state"+action.type); 
  switch(action.type) {
   case USER_LOGIN:{
    return { ...state, message: action.payload.message,   token:action.payload.token,loggedin:true};
   }
   case USER_LOGINING:{
     return {...state,logging:true }
   }
   default:{
     console.log("default "+action.type); 
   }
  }
  return state;
}
```

index.js // combine reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import drawer from './drawer';
import AuthReducer from './auth_reducer';
import CoreReducer from './core_reducer';


export default combineReducers({
 auth: AuthReducer, 

});
```

i have created and configured the store and wrapped my app with the provider from react-redux, and i have passed the store to the provider, in a nutshell i can now access the store from my componets. 
below is a function in my login_component, that triggers once i click on login

```
login(){
  if(this.state.email==""){
    alert("Email require"); 
    return;
  }else if(this.state.password==""){
    alert("password require"); 
    return;
  }else{
    //set the paramter for the reducer to use
    this.props.username(this.state.email);
    this.props.password(this.state.password);
    //activate the user login action

    this.props.UserLogin(); 

    if(!this.props.auth.loggedin){
     console.log("logging in");
     //show loadging gif
    }
    //checking from response from the auth api
    if(this.props.auth.message=="user successfully logged in"){
        alert(this.props.auth.token);
        Actions.home();
      }else{
        alert("invalid Username/Password"); 
      }      
    }
}
```

Now this is problem, once i click on login, the block of code i commented (check response from api) will not wait for the store value to change before it perform it action, please i need a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

i finally got a solution to the problem, the api call was async but the problem was that in the component, i tested for the response before the store changes so here is the solution, i added the following to my login component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 console.log("component update"); 
  if(nextProps.auth.loggedin==true){

    if(nextProps.auth.message=="user successfully logged in"){
        this.setState(previousState => {
          return { spinnerv: false };
         });
        Actions.home();
    }else{
        alert("invalid Username/Password"); 
    }  
  }
}
```

what happens here is that function componentWillReceiveProps, check if the states has changed and then text if the response is componentWillReceiveProps.
thanks jmargolisvt for your support.
i hope this help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform this API call asynchronously.  Basically, you will have your login function dispatch an async action that will make the API call.  Then from your success/fail methods of the API call, you'll dispatch another (synchronous) call that either logs the user in or not.

You'll want to incorporate Redux Thunks to make your async call. 
 https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: thanks so much at jmargolisvt, but if you look at my code, you will see that i have done all that you said, the api call is synchronous and i dispatched an action USER_LOGIN, which my reducer uses that to update the state.message, but the problem the login() function in my login component fire up the UserLogin() action and uses the state to validate the user,  but the state get updated late because of api call

Comment: " the api call is synchronous" -- needs to be async

Comment: i have solved the problem now, the api call was actually async, you can see that in the code above i dispatached an action after the api call returns, but i was not doing right was i didnot tell the component to recieve the new props